# Using Multiple IPs for the same interface for different application?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ip, ifconfig

I want to do some IP aliasing, but I want my browser to use a different IP from the IP for BitTorrent.

For example:

I want the browser to use this IP for example 192.168.1.45
and BitTorrent to use 192.168.1.46

Comment: Hm, I know how to set this up for incomming connections but not how to set applications to use different ip addresses for their connections to the outside.